# Capture and Crop Image and save croped Image

Tags: android, android-studio, android-intent, crop

I am trying to capture an image and save cropped image instead of original image with specified name.
At the moment I am able to crop and show on imageview but I need to know how to save cropped image instead of original, Here is the code.

```
final int CAMERA_CAPTURE = 1;
final int CROP_PIC = 2;
private Uri picUri;

@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button captureBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.capture_btn);
        captureBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v.getId() == R.id.capture_btn) {
            try {
                // use standard intent to capture an image
                Intent captureIntent = new Intent(
                        MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                // we will handle the returned data in onActivityResult
                startActivityForResult(captureIntent, CAMERA_CAPTURE);
            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "This device doesn't support the crop action!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.show();
            }
        }
    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == CAMERA_CAPTURE) {
                // get the Uri for the captured image
                picUri = data.getData();
                performCrop();
            }
            // user is returning from cropping the image
            else if (requestCode == CROP_PIC) {
                // get the returned data
                Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
                // get the cropped bitmap
                Bitmap thePic = extras.getParcelable("data");
                ImageView picView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.picture);
                picView.setImageBitmap(thePic);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * this function does the crop operation.
     */
    private void performCrop() {
        // take care of exceptions
        try {
            // call the standard crop action intent (the user device may not
            // support it)
            Intent cropIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
            // indicate image type and Uri
            cropIntent.setDataAndType(picUri, "image/*");
            // set crop properties
            cropIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
            // indicate aspect of desired crop
            cropIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 2);
            cropIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
            // indicate output X and Y
            cropIntent.putExtra("outputX", 256);
            cropIntent.putExtra("outputY", 256);
            // retrieve data on return
            cropIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
            // start the activity - we handle returning in onActivityResult
            startActivityForResult(cropIntent, CROP_PIC);
        }
        // respond to users whose devices do not support the crop action
        catch (ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
            Toast toast = Toast
                    .makeText(this, "This device doesn't support the crop action!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
        }
    }
```

I am new to android and I really want to know how I can do this, any kind of help is much appriciated.

Comment: [Android does not have a `CROP` `Intent`](https://commonsware.com/blog/2013/01/23/no-android-does-not-have-crop-intent.html). There are many [image cropping libraries available for Android](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/45). Please use one.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Android does not have any crop intent you can download crop libraries  [Click here](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/45)

Comment: Some does support this intent.

Answer (score 0):

So the question is: How to save a `bitmap`

Sometimes saving bitmaps takes a long time. I suggest you to use AsyncTask in order to avoid annoying lags in your app.

```
public class saveFile extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, File>{
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {

            super.onPreExecute();

            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);//Show user that app is working in backgrind

        }


        @Override
        protected File doInBackground(Void... params) {

            String file_path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() +
                    "/CropedImage";

            File dir = new File(file_path);

            if(!dir.exists())

            dir.mkdirs();

            String format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss",
            java.util.Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());

            File file = new File(dir, format + ".png");

            FileOutputStream fOut;

            try {

            fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);

            thePic.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fOut);

            fOut.flush();

            fOut.close();

            } 

            catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

            }


                return file;
        }

         @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(File result) {

            progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            String respath=result.getPath().toString();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Saved at "+respath, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(MainActivity.this, new String[] { result.getPath() }, new String[] { "image/jpeg" }, null);     





          }
    }
```

And then call AsyncTask:

```
 new saveFile().execute();
```

Comment: where do I need to use AsyncTask? I mean I have to create new class?

Comment: No no, just add it inside your MainActivity.class

Comment: Kindly elaborate your suggested solution with my code. I am not understanding how to follow your suggested code. I am geting uri and getting that uri to read into bitmap.